# UWP - opening intranet pages on default browser

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am trying to open a page restricted for intranet users which authenticates with single sign-on. However, I am unable to do this through UWP (fairly new to UWP so still haven't figured out the new namespaces and classes).
I have tried the code below:

```
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("https://abccompany.net"));
```

Now if I replace the url with google.com, this seems to work fine. However this fails for my enterprise's websites.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You mean it fails to open intranet page with default browser but opens it with another browser?

Comment: It doesn't do anything. I use the LaunchUriAsync method to launch the Windows store. Whereas when I used this to launch an intranet page it never throws and error, but neither does it open it. I have also tried treating it as an untrusted page (using the LauncherOptions class), to see if I receive a prompt. But doesn't do anything as long as its a page from my company's portal.

Comment: can the intranet site be opened in IE, but not Edge? Sounds like an compatibility issue.

Comment: The site opens up in Edge and IE and chrome (probably other browsers too). However I need to be connected to VPN. My tests with LaunchUriAsync fails regardless of being connected to VPN or not.

Comment: The remark section in [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.launcher.launchuriasync#Windows_System_Launcher_LaunchUriAsync_Windows_Foundation_Uri_) has some information about having to specify `privateNetworkClientServer` capability to access intranet uri, please verify.

Comment: Thanks. That worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Remarks section of [Launcher.LaunchUriAsync Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.launcher.launchuriasync#Windows_System_Launcher_LaunchUriAsync_Windows_Foundation_Uri_):

> You must specify the privateNetworkClientServer capability in the manifest in order to launch intranet URIs, for example a file:/// URI pointing to a network location.

You can do this by checking the Private Networks (Client and Server) option in the Capabilities section of Package Manifest.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Kennyzx. Just to add to your answer there, you can do this by checking the Private Networks (Client and Server) option in the Capabilities section of Package Manifest.

Comment: RamyaN, update my answer according to your comment to explicitly describe the step to make it work, the `privateNetworkClientServer` is the value that is set to the `appxmanifest` file.